# INNER JOIN with a COUNTER COLUMN?

Tags: sql

so basically I have a two tables

tblmember

```
MemberID      Name      LastName      Age      Gender
200           Sample    Guy           23       Male
201           Sample    Girl          24       Female
```

tblrecord

```
ID      MemberID        LoginDate      Status
1       200             3/27/2021      Login
2       200             3/27/2021      Logout
3       200             3/27/2021      Login
4       201             3/26/2021      Login
5       201             3/26/2021      Logout
```

what I wanted to do is like this

```
MemberID      Name      LastName      Age      Gender       Login      Logouts
200           Sample    Guy           23       Male         2          1
201           Sample    Girl          24       Female       1          1
```

but the only query i know is

```
select a.MemberID, Name, LastName, Age, Gender
from tblmember a
inner join tblrecords b
on a.MemberID = b.MemberID
```

how do I add the Login and logouts counter ?
I am sorry i am really noob at this. please dont hate me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the columns of your `tblmember` table. Then you can use aggregate functions like `sum()` to get the count of each of those records

```
select a.MemberID, a.Name, a.LastName, a.Age, a.Gender,
       sum(case when b.status = 'Login' then 1 else 0 end) as Logins,
       sum(case when b.status = 'Logout' then 1 else 0 end) as Logouts
from tblmember a
inner join tblrecords b on a.MemberID = b.MemberID
group by a.MemberID, a.Name, a.LastName, a.Age, a.Gender
```

Comment: its says Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Comment: got it. just had to delete comma. thank you!